# Can't show ProgessDialog using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I use asynctask to get data from web services. But progessdialog not show when thread execute

```
private class Task_Bank extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>>{
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<String> arrayBankL = new ArrayList<String>();
            String url="http://qhoang.org/webservices/get_list_bank.php";
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser.getJSONFromURL(url);
            int i = 0;
            try{
                JSONArray array_bank = jsonObject.getJSONArray("list_bank");
                for(i=0;i<array_bank.length();i++){
                    JSONObject node = array_bank.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject c = node.getJSONObject("node_list_bank");
                    String namebank = c.getString("tennganhang");
                    arrayBankL.add(namebank);
                }
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return arrayBankL;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter_bank = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TaskAActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,result);
            arrayAdapter_bank.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spn_bank.setAdapter(arrayAdapter_bank);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            ProgressDialog MyDialog = ProgressDialog.show( TaskAActivity.this, " " , " Loading. Please wait ... ", true);
        }   
}
```

OnCreate()

```
Task_Bank a = new Task_Bank();
a.execute();
```

JSONParser is class i code to use parser JSON from webservices result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `show()` dialog in `onPreExecute()` that starts before task starting and is right place for this. in `onProgressUpdate` you should only increment progress for your `ProgressDialog`. and when task finished so in `onPostExecute()` call `MyDialog.dismiss()`

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
   progressDialog.show();           
}
```

It could be like this

```
ProgressDialog MyDialog = ProgressDialog.show(TaskAActivity.this, " " , " Loading. Please wait ... ", true);
// some settings
Task_Bank a = new Task_Bank();
a.execute();

@Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
      MyDialog.show();          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do some modifications in your code to show progress dialog.

> Start showing ProgressDialog in onPreExcecute.
>
> Stop Showing  progress dialog in onPostExcecute.

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setTitle("Hello");
        dialog.setMessage("Please Wait!!!");
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.show();
    }


@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
                ---------
}
```